# Laravel 4 Views

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a new user of both Stack Overflow and laravel.

I just started to learn L4 in their official site but now I'm having a small problem in loading the views.

Now my views is not working properly. Any file I call under the views dir results in "file doesn't exist" error.

This is my code ....

**Authors controller is:**

```
class AuthorController extends BaseController{

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index()
    {
    return View::make('authors.index');
    }
}
```

On `routes.php` I added

`Route::get('authors',array('uses'=>'authors@index'));`

under `views/authors/index.php`

Any html text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Route::get('authors',array('uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

to

```
Route::get('authors',array('uses'=>'AuthorController@get_index'));
```

Comment: Oh yeah.... I got that...but forgot to send a regard ....thanks hammurabi..  a good ime help

Answer (score 1):

If you dont plan on doing complex logic you could skip the controller and just call the view from the router. And also its a good practice to keep the functions as camelCase so in your case getIndex().

```
Route::get('authors', 'AuthorController@getIndex');
```